# How can I get the items in this JSON file to display properly?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have these three items from a service and it is in JSON format. When I write out the loop to just display the artist name and the song I keep getting an error

This is the API command in server.js

```
app.post('/process_form', function(req, res){
    var search = req.body.search
    axios.get('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term='+search)
    .then((response)=>{
        var songlist = response.data.results;
        console.log(songlist);
        res.render('pages/thanks.ejs', {
            songlist: songlist,
            search: search
        });
    });
})
```

This is the code for the html form where the user can enter the name of a song or artist

```
        <form action="/process_form" method="post">
            <h1>Which song would you like to lookup</h1>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="search" name="search">
                </div>
            <input type="submit">
```

And this is the form where the results will be output in a list

```
    <ul>
        <% songlist.forEach(function(songlist) { %>
            <li>
                <strong><%= songlist[artistName] %></strong>
                <strong><%= songlist[TrackName] %></strong>
            </li>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>
```

This is what the original source of the data looks like.

```
 {
    wrapperType: 'track',
    kind: 'song',
    artistId: 216123617,
    collectionId: 982317323,
    trackId: 982317327,
    artistName: 'Rockabye Baby!',
    collectionName: 'Lullaby Renditions of Radiohead',
    trackName: 'Let Down',
  },
```

Lastly the error I get is that. I am just confused as to why it is saying that I did not define songList

```
    5|     <main>
    6|         <ul>
 >> 7|             <% songlist.forEach(function(songlist) { %>
    8|                 <li>
    9|                     <strong><%= songlist[artistName] %></strong>
    10|                     <strong><%= songlist[TrackName] %></strong>

songlist is not defined
```

Sorry for the long post. I am just super frustrated at this and I do not know what I am doing wrong

EDIT: I am using EJS as the view engine

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Comment: is that data the data that is returned when you console log it?

Comment: Yes it is. That is what is logged into the console. I am trying to grab the data from that and just output that as a list in html

Comment: what templating framework are you using?

Comment: Ejs, Javascript, and node. I am using axios to get the results back

Comment: did you set the [view engine to ejs](https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express#basic-setup)?

Comment: Yes is did. I will update the post with it

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution was that when was actually rendering my index file, I put

```
res.render(index)
```

When the file name was supposed to be

```
res.render(index.ejs)
```